# How do I make the user choose the name of the database?

Tags: vb.net

in my project i need some changes in my code to give the user choose the name of sql database !

and this is My original code:

```
            Dim DssD As String
    DssD = TextBox1.Text

    Zsql = "CREATE DATABASE my_db ON PRIMARY" +
        "(Name=my_db, filename = 'D:\DB\SQL\my_db.mdf')log on" +
        "(name=my_db_log, filename='D:\DB\SQL\my_db_log.ldf')"

    Zcmd = New SqlCommand(Zsql, Zsqlcon)
    Try
        Zsqlcon.Open()
        Zcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Zsqlcon.Close()

        MsgBox("Done", MsgBoxStyle.Information, " ZerAllail")
    Catch
        MsgBox("Somthing wrong", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " ZerAllail")
    End Try
```

its working good but its not create the log fail !

Comment: The name of the database is just a `String`. How would you usually get string input from the user?

Comment: i know that..but i mean if i can let the user write the database name in text-box as he like not as i do it in code ?

Comment: You say that you know that and then demonstrate that you don't. The database name is a `string` so you can get it in any way that you would normally get a `string` from the user. If you would normally get a `string` from the user via a `TextBox` then obviously you can do that to get this `string`. If what you're really asking is how do you then incorporate that into your SQL string then, again, it's just a `string` like any other, so how would you usually join multiple sunstrings together into a single `string`?

Comment: I don't pretend to know something I don't know it , When I said I know this, I mean I know that the name of the database is a String like any other String , and all i ask for it did i can let the user to type the name that he want for database in the text_box  Which is defined by the variable DssD To be approved as the name of the database, so if you know tell me or Maybe some one do !

Comment: The benefit of this site is that it allows you to have questions answered that you are unable to figure out for yourself. It is not intended for questions that you can't be bothered to figure out for yourself. If you can try something for yourself then there's no reason to ask about it here. If you try it and it doesn't work, then you have a question to ask and you can explain to us what you're trying to achieve, how you tried to achieve it, what you expected and what you actually saw. There are questions appropriate for this site and others that are not. Yours is not.

Comment: *"i can let the user to type the name that he want for database in the text_box"*. What happened when you tried? If you haven't tried, why not? What is stopping you?

Comment: (jmcilhinney) You have 2 know that I never ask a question here before I try to figure out with myself , but if i cant i try to ask here, and There is no necessity for all this lecture!
thanks

Comment: I don't have to know anything other than what you post here. I'm not psychic. If you have already tried and it didn't work as expected, you are supposed to include all that information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a interpolated string (preceded with `$`) if you are using Visual Studio 2015 or later. You can embed variables directly into the string enclosed in braces. Otherwise see `String.Format`.

I added a `Using...End Using` block to your code because connections and commands need to closed and disposed. They use unmanaged resources and need to release them in their `.Dispose` methods. A `Using` block will do this for you even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub CreateDatabase()
    Dim DssD = TextBox1.Text 'I would expect you would validata this input
    Dim Zsql = $"CREATE DATABASE {DssD} ON PRIMARY (Name=my_db, filename = 'D:\DB\SQL\{DssD}.mdf')log on 
        (name={DssD}_log, filename='D:\DB\SQL\{DssD}_log.ldf')"
    Try
        Using Zsqlcon As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            Zcmd = New SqlCommand(Zsql, Zsqlcon)
            Zsqlcon.Open()
            Zcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MsgBox("Done", MsgBoxStyle.Information, " ZerAllail")
    Catch
        MsgBox("Somthing wrong", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " ZerAllail")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Somthing wrong in this code (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.') i believe its need some change ! :) Thanks pro.

Comment: I did not check the syntax of your Sql command. Do a `Debug.Print(Zsql)` and look at the  string.

Comment: When i remove The Under Score after log on the code works good. Anyhow, you have no idea how much your code helped me. Thanks very much.

Comment: You are correct. I am sorry, I don't know where my mind was. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: whatever you are great - Mary :)